# Displaying Context Menu where mouse was rightclicked

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, user-interface, wpf-controls

I have a created a contextMenu in a DiagramSurface .I am displaying the context Menu on the rightclick .I am facing problem in the positioning of the contextMenu. It is appearing at random placed everytime.   Can i fix the position of display.

I have tried this

```
<DiagramSurface  ContextMenuService.Placement="MousePoint" >
<DiagramSurface.contextMenu>  
<contextMenu name ="ContextMenuVariable">
<MenuItem Header="Save" Click="MenuClick" />
</contextMenu>
</DiagramSurface.contextMenu>
</DiagramSurface>
```

what am  doing wrong? i want to diaplay the contextMenu next to mouseclick location.

Comment: add code..i think you missed it..

Comment: your code is fine is you use canvas in place of Drawingsurface..i don't have telekik so i can't check for that..but what i think ..it should work for drawingsurface too..just check is thr problem anywhere else